# .htaccess replace RedirectMatch with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I've tried to convert the working RedirectMatch in my .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/babysearch/(faq|whats-new|gallery|daily-winners|prizes) /babysearch
```

to a RewriteRule, however it does not work

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/(faq|whats-new|gallery|daily-winners|prizes)$ /blog/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

thats my mod_rewrite.c tag

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [QSA,L]

    RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(faq|whats-new|gallery|daily-winners|prizes) /blog
</ifModule>
```

Thoughts

Comment: The issue is that a `RewriteRule` operates on the _relative_ path component of the requested URL when implemented in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"). So your matching pattern needs to start with `^blog/`, not `^/blog/` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Please clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^blog/(faq|whats-new|gallery|daily-winners|prizes)/?$ /blog/ [R=301,NC,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
</ifModule>
```

***Fixes in OP's attempts:***

- Make sure your redirection is before non-existing check Rules.
- Then you need to remove starting `^/` from your redirection rule because that will never meet.
- We need not to mention `^(.*)` in index rewrite just mention `^` there.